# Understanding dw And &H8000& in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6

I was tasked with writing an application that's already been written in Visual Basic 6 in C# for my internship. While I was doing this, I came across the this in the vb6 application's code:

```
Public Function LoWord(dw As Long) As Integer

 If dw And &H8000& Then
       LoWord = &H8000 Or (dw And &H7FFF&)
 Else: LoWord = dw And &HFFFF&
 End If

 End Function
```

I don't understand how I can evaluate "dw And &H8000&" as true or false in C#. If I try using "dw && 0x8000" I get an error message saying I can't use the logical AND operator between the two types. However, if I try "dw & 0x8000" I get an error saying the type being passed to the if statement can't be converted into a bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB6's "if" statement uses the classic convention of 0 meaning false, non-zero meaning true. The direct C# equivalent is `(dw & 0x8000)!=0`, though you can probably do the bit twiddling in other ways if one wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bitwise operation. You have to say

```
if ((dw & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
{
    ...
}
```

The result of `(dw & 0x8000)` is an integer.

If the idea is just to get the lower 16 bits of the integer as a signed number, you could always just replace the whole calculation with:

```
return (int)((short)(value & 0xFFFF));
```

The cast to short and then back to int sign extends the value.